# How to Put point of interest in unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a wall in Home sweet 3d with some pictures on it and I imported it as a .obj  and opened in unity 3d. I want to put a button next (point of interest) to every image So that on click to the button, a popup should appear with some text.

Answer (score 1):

GameObject -> UI -> Button
create a button and move it in your scene
change the sprite to whatever you want it to look like
attach a script to an object in the scene with a method to show your popup
add the method to your button's onclick

Comment: how to fix the position of a button. I wanted a button to remain on the wall when I created a button it walks with me wherever I move, it also moves

Comment: it sounds like you have added it as a child to your character, drag it out onto the hierarchy from underneath the character